# Call Activator.CreateInstance in a dll to intance class that reside inside Asp.Net App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies, activator, createinstance

Help, here is the idea:

```
External.dll
IMyClass NewCreated = (IMyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(Namespace.MyClass).UnWrap();

-----------------------------------------

Asp.Net WebSite
    App_Code
      Namespace.MyClass.cs
    Bin
      External.dll
```

Is that even posible?

I have tried, a lot of posible combinations, like:

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CreateInstance("Namespace.MyClass")
Activator.CreateInstance(AppDomain.CurrentDomain,"Namespace","Namespace.MyClass")
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Namespace.MyClass")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BuildManager.CodeAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to list all the assembly names that have been compiled in the App_Code directory.  You may be able to accomplish what you need that way.

The problem with App_Code is that everything gets dynamically compiled into an assembly that is by nature, temporary.  This comes along with a temporary assembly name.  This makes it impossible to hardcode an assembly name or path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is the complete code for initializing any class in app_code from a dll.

Activator.CreateInstance(((Assembly)BuildManager.CodeAssemblies[0]).GetType("Namespace.Class"), ConstructorParams1,ConstructorParams2);

Answer (score 0):

No need use the BuildManager.CodeAssemblies property to list all the assembly names. Instead use:

type="Namespace.MyClass, App_Code" to reference the class.